# how to recover Ubuntu terminal path?

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-14.04

Actually, my path was jjw or jjw/home

but when i run Terminal, it become

[image]

how do i return original path?

Comment: This question does not seem to have anything to do with programming, and should be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pwd` - return working directory name (PWD - Print Working Directory)